# How do I add an extra step in a Heroku Pipeline?

Tags: heroku

We need two extra columns / swimlanes in our pipeline, so that we can have 4 environments (*dev* / *test* / staging / production).

How is this configured?

[image: heroku image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add new stages. Only `development`, `staging` and `production` are currently supported, and `review` if you are using GitHub.